# Embedding images in rythm template

Tags: java, html-email, template-engine, rythm

I'm using Rythm template engine to send template email from my java code. But when I try to embed an image using  tag, The image doesn't appear in the mail.

```
<img src="college.png">
```

Can anybody tell me how can I embed images in rythm template?
If rythm engine can't handle this suggest me a better template engine.

Thank you.

Comment: I think no one (unmodified) template engine can processs such task. Engine perform ONLY with text. What API do You use for mailing? Must append image

Comment: I use mailgun web api with jursey library.

Comment: What happens when you link to an image hosted online? Like <img src=" http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png  ">

Comment: Agree with @JacekCz, you need the absolute URL path to the image in order to get it visible in an email. This is not relevant to template engine.

Comment: It seems that hosting the image is the only solution that I have. Thank you all  of you for your suggestions and ideas.